# H2O cluster shuts down unexpectedly; packet_write_wait: Connection to xxx.xxx.xx.xx port 22: Broken pipe

Tags: h2o

After running a long process (~2 hours) process on an h2o instance (version 3.24.0.2 (Hadoop)), the python script appears to lose connection and errors out with message

```sh
...
File "/home/osboxes/projects/ml1c/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/h2o.py", line 274, in init
    raise H2OConnectionError('Can only start H2O launcher if IP address is localhost.')
H2OConnectionError: Can only start H2O launcher if IP address is localhost.
```

Checking the h2o instance that was started before running the script the terminal output after presssing `enter` shows

```sh
...
H2O node 172.18.4.62:54321 reports H2O cluster size 5 [leader is 172.18.4.62:54321]
H2O node 172.18.4.66:54321 reports H2O cluster size 5 [leader is 172.18.4.62:54321]
H2O node 172.18.4.65:54321 reports H2O cluster size 5 [leader is 172.18.4.62:54321]
H2O cluster (5 nodes) is up
(Note: Use the -disown option to exit the driver after cluster formation)

Open H2O Flow in your web browser: http://172.18.4.62:54321

(Press Ctrl-C to kill the cluster)
Blocking until the H2O cluster shuts down...
packet_write_wait: Connection to 172.18.4.62 port 22: Broken pipe
```

Anyone know what can be done to fix this?

- For context I am processing a large pandas dataframe by rowwise-chunks, converting them into h2o dataframe, and putting them back together with row binding `h2o.rbind`.

Comment: can you look at your logs and see if there are any warnings about running out of memory? Can you also say whether your connection is timing out or not? thanks!

Comment: @Lauren While I am currently assuming that that is the problem, can't verify by the logs, since when the error happens the cluster just shuts down (so can't go to the Flow UI to examine the logs).

Comment: here are the instructions for how to get the logs after h2o has shutdown: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/logs.html

Comment: @Lauren Forgot to mention that was not able to get the logs from the YARN web UI either. Seeing error message 
"Failed while trying to construct the redirect url to the log server. Log Server url may not be configured
java.lang.Exception: Unknown container. Container either has not started or has already completed or doesn't belong to this node at all."
Continuing to debug the issue.